# running grep command in command line and from java code gives different results

Tags: java, command-line

When I run the below grep command in terminal, I get the list of line numbers. But when i tried doing the same via java code i didn't any result. I am not sure what went wrong here.

Thank in advance

```
grep -in "callback recieved" /home/local/ws/ui_auto/UIAutomator/result/test/logs | cut -f1 -d:


public List<Integer> getLineNumbers(String pattern, String file, String pat) {
    String[] cmd = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "grep -in \""+ pattern + "\" " + file + " | cut -f1 -d:"}; // > " + file + "_" + pat };
    System.out.println(cmd[2]);
    Process proc;
    List<Integer> rline = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    try {
        proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            rline.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return rline;
}
```

Comment: Does it throws any error or exception?probably your command string is a issue.should't it be "grep -in"  instead of "grep -in \" .And try using processsbuilder for it.As you are passing many arguements so probably that will be a better choice.For purpose of seeing that what has gone wrong.Take errorStream from proc and check that what error has occured?

Comment: tried using ProcessBuilder, didn't work. I suspected the command takes time to finish exection, so i add sleep of 1 second before "proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);" , it worked. I couldn't understand whats happening, an how to correct it.

Comment: I have added a answer as a probable solution.Let me know , if it works for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

As per as our discussion in comments.If putting a sleeep of 1 second has worked for you. Try putting  :

```
proc.waitFor();
```

> Process.waitFor() blocks the current thread until the process has
>   terminated, at which point the execution control returns to the thread
>   that spawned the process.

Put it after: proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);